# Pandas ewm doesn't match marketwatch

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a 5 minute feed and storing it in the dataframe. My EWM 200 doesn't match Marketwatch EWM 200

I've tried the piece of code posted on Feb 13th 2018. My data has dates already sorted in ascending order and for some reason, it doesn't do the trick

```
    df = df.drop(df.index[-1])
    print(df[['date','low','close']])
    df.sort_values(by='date')
    df = df.sort_index()
    print(df[['date','low','close']])

#print(df)
    df['ewm_5'] = round(df['close'].ewm(span=5,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean(),2)
    df['ewm_9'] = round(df['close'].ewm(span=9,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean(),2)
    df['ewm_15'] = df['close'].ewm(span=15,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    df['ewm_65'] = df['close'].ewm(span=65,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    df['ewm_200'] = df['close'].ewm(span=200,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    print(df[['date','low','close','ewm_9','ewm_15','ewm_65', 'ewm_200','volume']])
```

Marketwatch at 630AM says ewm 200 is 155.70 and mine says 161.78 when I use the function

```
df['ewm_200'] = df['close'].ewm(span=200,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
```

Here is my updated raw data with more than 200 datapoints by 630 AM and still mine and market watch dont conincide or even close to each other. Mine now says: 159.036336 and market watch is at 155.70.

```
               date     low   close   ewm_9      ewm_15      ewm_65     ewm_200  volume
```

0    20190214  04:15:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       1
1    20190214  04:20:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
2    20190214  04:25:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
3    20190214  04:30:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
4    20190214  04:35:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
5    20190214  04:40:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
6    20190214  04:45:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
7    20190214  04:50:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
8    20190214  04:55:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
9    20190214  05:00:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
10   20190214  05:05:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
11   20190214  05:10:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
12   20190214  05:15:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
13   20190214  05:20:00  153.51  153.51  153.51  153.510000  153.510000  153.510000       0
14   20190214  05:25:00  153.50  153.50  153.51  153.508750  153.509697  153.509900       1
15   20190214  05:30:00  153.50  153.50  153.51  153.507656  153.509403  153.509802       0
16   20190214  05:35:00  153.50  153.50  153.51  153.506699  153.509118  153.509704       0
17   20190214  05:40:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.505862  153.508842  153.509608       0
18   20190214  05:45:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.505129  153.508574  153.509512       0
19   20190214  05:50:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.504488  153.508314  153.509418       0
20   20190214  05:55:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.503927  153.508062  153.509324       0
21   20190214  06:00:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.503436  153.507818  153.509231       0
22   20190214  06:05:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.503007  153.507581  153.509139       0
23   20190214  06:10:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.502631  153.507351  153.509048       0
24   20190214  06:15:00  153.50  153.50  153.50  153.502302  153.507128  153.508958       0
25   20190214  06:20:00  153.70  153.70  153.54  153.527014  153.512973  153.510859       1
26   20190214  06:25:00  153.70  153.70  153.57  153.548637  153.518641  153.512741       0
27   20190214  06:30:00  153.70  153.70  153.60  153.567558  153.524136  153.514605       0
28   20190214  06:35:00  153.70  153.70  153.62  153.584113  153.529465  153.516449       0
29   20190214  06:40:00  153.70  153.70  153.63  153.598599  153.534633  153.518276       0
30   20190214  06:45:00  153.70  153.70  153.65  153.611274  153.539644  153.520084       0
31   20190214  06:50:00  153.70  153.70  153.66  153.622365  153.544504  153.521874       0
32   20190214  06:55:00  153.70  153.70  153.67  153.632069  153.549216  153.523646       0
33   20190214  07:00:00  153.81  154.05  153.74  153.684311  153.564391  153.528884      31
34   20190214  07:05:00  154.00  154.00  153.79  153.723772  153.577591  153.533572       3
35   20190214  07:10:00  154.07  154.37  153.91  153.804550  153.601604  153.541894      19
36   20190214  07:15:00  154.16  154.20  153.97  153.853981  153.619737  153.548442      15
37   20190214  07:20:00  154.28  154.56  154.09  153.942234  153.648230  153.558508      17
38   20190214  07:25:00  154.47  154.48  154.16  154.009455  153.673435  153.567677       5
39   20190214  07:30:00  154.43  154.43  154.22  154.062023  153.696361  153.576257       2
40   20190214  07:35:00  154.50  154.50  154.27  154.116770  153.720714  153.585449      30
41   20190214  07:40:00  154.50  154.50  154.32  154.164674  153.744328  153.594549      10
42   20190214  07:45:00  154.37  154.45  154.35  154.200339  153.765712  153.603061      20
43   20190214  07:50:00  154.35  154.35  154.35  154.219047  153.783418  153.610493      13
44   20190214  07:55:00  154.26  154.30  154.34  154.229166  153.799072  153.617354      29
45   20190214  08:00:00  153.90  154.17  154.30  154.221770  153.810312  153.622853     122
46   20190214  08:05:00  154.24  154.40  154.32  154.244049  153.828182  153.630585      26
47   20190214  08:10:00  154.37  154.43  154.34  154.267293  153.846419  153.638540      29
48   20190214  08:15:00  154.49  154.50  154.38  154.296381  153.866224  153.647111       6
49   20190214  08:20:00  154.45  154.45  154.39  154.315584  153.883914  153.655100      16
50   20190214  08:25:00  154.25  154.26  154.36  154.308636  153.895311  153.661119      18
51   20190214  08:30:00  153.97  154.02  154.30  154.272556  153.899089  153.664690     168
52   20190214  08:35:00  153.71  153.97  154.23  154.234737  153.901238  153.667728     165
53   20190214  08:40:00  153.50  153.51  154.09  154.144145  153.889382  153.666159     114
54   20190214  08:45:00  153.33  153.34  153.94  154.043627  153.872734  153.662913      57
55   20190214  08:50:00  153.40  153.71  153.89  154.001923  153.867803  153.663382      43
56   20190214  08:55:00  153.04  153.19  153.75  153.900433  153.847264  153.658672     142
57   20190214  09:00:00  152.25  152.51  153.50  153.726629  153.806740  153.647242      48
58   20190214  09:05:00  152.50  152.93  153.39  153.627050  153.780173  153.640105     139
59   20190214  09:10:00  152.55  152.75  153.26  153.517419  153.748955  153.631249      69
60   20190214  09:15:00  152.68  152.90  153.19  153.440242  153.723229  153.623972      82
61   20190214  09:20:00  152.50  152.50  153.05  153.322711  153.686162  153.612789      29
62   20190214  09:25:00  152.50  152.97  153.03  153.278622  153.664460  153.606393      21
63   20190214  09:30:00  151.10  152.30  152.89  153.156295  153.623113  153.593394    5143
64   20190214  09:35:00  151.97  153.76  153.06  153.231758  153.627261  153.595052    5437
65   20190214  09:40:00  153.12  153.39  153.13  153.251538  153.620071  153.593011    4097
66   20190214  09:45:00  152.75  153.71  153.24  153.308846  153.622796  153.594175    3310
67   20190214  09:50:00  153.36  154.53  153.50  153.461490  153.650287  153.603487    3637
68   20190214  09:55:00  154.39  155.29  153.86  153.690054  153.699975  153.620268    5561
69   20190214  10:00:00  154.96  155.12  154.11  153.868797  153.743006  153.635191    3372
70   20190214  10:05:00  154.75  154.76  154.24  153.980197  153.773824  153.646383    2327
71   20190214  10:10:00  154.47  154.58  154.31  154.055173  153.798254  153.655673    2215
72   20190214  10:15:00  154.15  154.49  154.35  154.109526  153.819216  153.663975    2565
73   20190214  10:20:00  154.21  154.33  154.34  154.137085  153.834694  153.670602    2410
74   20190214  10:25:00  153.75  154.10  154.29  154.132450  153.842734  153.674874    2822
75   20190214  10:30:00  153.77  153.91  154.22  154.104644  153.844772  153.677214    2188
76   20190214  10:35:00  152.31  152.57  153.89  153.912813  153.806143  153.666197    3800
77   20190214  10:40:00  152.56  153.11  153.73  153.812461  153.785048  153.660663    2184
78   20190214  10:45:00  153.10  154.26  153.84  153.868404  153.799440  153.666626    2952
79   20190214  10:50:00  153.82  153.85  153.84  153.866103  153.800972  153.668451    1483
80   20190214  10:55:00  153.46  153.98  153.87  153.880340  153.806397  153.671551    1842
81   20190214  11:00:00  153.32  153.46  153.79  153.827798  153.795900  153.669446    1386
82   20190214  11:05:00  153.33  153.84  153.80  153.829323  153.797237  153.671143     963
83   20190214  11:10:00  153.55  153.81  153.80  153.826908  153.797623  153.672524    1048
84   20190214  11:15:00  153.80  153.95  153.83  153.842294  153.802241  153.675285    1344
85   20190214  11:20:00  153.79  153.88  153.84  153.847007  153.804597  153.677322     859
86   20190214  11:25:00  153.61  153.75  153.82  153.834882  153.802943  153.678046     731
87   20190214  11:30:00  153.35  153.38  153.73  153.778021  153.790126  153.675080    1137
88   20190214  11:35:00  153.37  153.60  153.71  153.755769  153.784365  153.674333     814
89   20190214  11:40:00  153.40  153.42  153.65  153.713798  153.773324  153.671802     954
90   20190214  11:45:00  153.36  153.60  153.64  153.699573  153.768071  153.671088    1370
91   20190214  11:50:00  153.27  153.29  153.57  153.648376  153.753584  153.667296    2310
92   20190214  11:55:00  153.16  153.40  153.54  153.617329  153.742870  153.664636     727
93   20190214  12:00:00  153.13  153.37  153.50  153.586413  153.731571  153.661704     928
94   20190214  12:05:00  153.36  153.55  153.51  153.581861  153.726068  153.660593     721
95   20190214  12:10:00  153.35  153.53  153.52  153.575379  153.720127  153.659293     840
96   20190214  12:15:00  153.52  154.03  153.62  153.632206  153.729517  153.662982    1047
97   20190214  12:20:00  153.91  154.20  153.73  153.703181  153.743774  153.668326     961
98   20190214  12:25:00  154.05  154.34  153.86  153.782783  153.761842  153.675009     872
99   20190214  12:30:00  154.25  154.49  153.98  153.871185  153.783907  153.683118    1223
100  20190214  12:35:00  154.41  154.53  154.09  153.953537  153.806516  153.691545    1276
101  20190214  12:40:00  154.51  154.70  154.21  154.046845  153.833591  153.701579     942
102  20190214  12:45:00  154.63  154.66  154.30  154.123489  153.858634  153.711116     957
103  20190214  12:50:00  154.55  154.60  154.36  154.183053  153.881099  153.719960     687
104  20190214  12:55:00  154.61  154.84  154.46  154.265171  153.910157  153.731105    1217
105  20190214  13:00:00  154.70  154.71  154.51  154.320775  153.934395  153.740845    1945
106  20190214  13:05:00  154.52  154.74  154.55  154.373178  153.958807  153.750787     768
107  20190214  13:10:00  154.51  154.63  154.57  154.405281  153.979146  153.759536     819
108  20190214  13:15:00  154.51  154.59  154.57  154.428371  153.997657  153.767799     674
109  20190214  13:20:00  154.27  154.41  154.54  154.426074  154.010152  153.774189     708
110  20190214  13:25:00  154.28  154.46  154.52  154.430315  154.023784  153.781013     727
111  20190214  13:30:00  154.29  154.35  154.49  154.420276  154.033669  153.786675     814
112  20190214  13:35:00  154.27  154.35  154.46  154.411491  154.043255  153.792280     859
113  20190214  13:40:00  154.30  154.44  154.46  154.415055  154.055278  153.798725     632
114  20190214  13:45:00  154.37  154.46  154.46  154.420673  154.067542  153.805305    1216
115  20190214  13:50:00  154.43  154.45  154.46  154.424339  154.079132  153.811719     709
116  20190214  13:55:00  154.34  154.38  154.44  154.418797  154.088249  153.817374    1004
117  20190214  14:00:00  153.99  154.06  154.36  154.373947  154.087393  153.819788     907
118  20190214  14:05:00  154.05  154.16  154.32  154.347204  154.089593  153.823173     626
119  20190214  14:10:00  154.04  154.12  154.28  154.318803  154.090514  153.826127     521
120  20190214  14:15:00  154.09  154.16  154.26  154.298953  154.092620  153.829449     659
121  20190214  14:20:00  154.11  154.35  154.28  154.305334  154.100419  153.834629     737
122  20190214  14:25:00  154.24  154.28  154.28  154.302167  154.105861  153.839060    1391
123  20190214  14:30:00  153.98  154.32  154.29  154.304396  154.112350  153.843846    1289
124  20190214  14:35:00  154.16  154.22  154.27  154.293847  154.115612  153.847588     692
125  20190214  14:40:00  154.05  154.18  154.25  154.279616  154.117564  153.850896     883
126  20190214  14:45:00  153.98  154.04  154.21  154.249664  154.115213  153.852778     792
127  20190214  14:50:00  153.83  154.03  154.18  154.222206  154.112631  153.854541    1201
128  20190214  14:55:00  153.75  153.87  154.11  154.178180  154.105278  153.854695    1094
129  20190214  15:00:00  153.84  153.97  154.09  154.152158  154.101179  153.855842    1212
130  20190214  15:05:00  153.94  154.28  154.12  154.168138  154.106598  153.860063    2079
131  20190214  15:10:00  153.91  154.06  154.11  154.154621  154.105186  153.862052    1125
132  20190214  15:15:00  154.05  154.15  154.12  154.154043  154.106544  153.864917    1284
133  20190214  15:20:00  154.01  154.02  154.10  154.137288  154.103921  153.866460    1073
134  20190214  15:25:00  153.95  154.08  154.10  154.130127  154.103196  153.868585    2261
135  20190214  15:30:00  153.92  153.92  154.06  154.103861  154.097645  153.869097    1736
136  20190214  15:35:00  153.83  154.05  154.06  154.097128  154.096201  153.870897    1809
137  20190214  15:40:00  154.00  154.10  154.07  154.097487  154.096316  153.873176    2143
138  20190214  15:45:00  154.01  154.25  154.10  154.116551  154.100973  153.876926    2935
139  20190214  15:50:00  154.23  154.38  154.16  154.149482  154.109429  153.881932    4572
140  20190214  15:55:00  154.31  154.53  154.23  154.197047  154.122173  153.888380    5166
141  20190214  16:00:00  154.29  154.30  154.25  154.209916  154.127562  153.892476    4169
142  20190214  16:05:00  154.13  154.49  154.30  154.244927  154.138545  153.898421     174
143  20190214  16:10:00  154.01  154.40  154.32  154.264311  154.146468  153.903412     109
144  20190214  16:15:00  154.30  154.95  154.44  154.350022  154.170817  153.913826     157
145  20190214  16:20:00  154.50  163.74  156.30  155.523769  154.460793  154.011599    7078
146  20190214  16:25:00  163.00  168.55  158.75  157.152048  154.887738  154.156260    6894
147  20190214  16:30:00  166.67  166.86  160.37  158.365542  155.250534  154.282665    3482
148  20190214  16:35:00  166.21  167.03  161.70  159.448599  155.607488  154.409504    1863
149  20190214  16:40:00  165.10  166.00  162.56  160.267524  155.922412  154.524832    2184
150  20190214  16:45:00  165.13  166.00  163.25  160.984084  156.227794  154.639013    1633
151  20190214  16:50:00  165.50  166.29  163.86  161.647323  156.532709  154.754943    1110
152  20190214  16:55:00  165.70  165.90  164.27  162.178908  156.816566  154.865839     347
153  20190214  17:00:00  165.80  166.25  164.66  162.687794  157.102428  154.979115    1028
154  20190214  17:05:00  166.30  167.12  165.15  163.241820  157.405991  155.099920     491
155  20190214  17:10:00  167.00  167.40  165.60  163.761593  157.708840  155.222308     935
156  20190214  17:15:00  166.60  166.95  165.87  164.160144  157.988875  155.339002     571
157  20190214  17:20:00  166.76  167.40  166.18  164.565126  158.274060  155.459012     289
158  20190214  17:25:00  167.10  167.45  166.43  164.925735  158.552119  155.578325     601
159  20190214  17:30:00  166.75  166.85  166.52  165.166268  158.803570  155.690481     307
160  20190214  17:35:00  166.80  167.00  166.61  165.395485  159.051947  155.803014     297
161  20190214  17:40:00  167.00  167.25  166.74  165.627299  159.300373  155.916914     307
162  20190214  17:45:00  167.25  167.94  166.98  165.916387  159.562179  156.036547    1285
163  20190214  17:50:00  167.25  167.35  167.05  166.095588  159.798174  156.149118     501
164  20190214  17:55:00  166.59  166.80  167.00  166.183640  160.010351  156.255097     531
165  20190214  18:00:00  166.30  166.45  166.89  166.216935  160.205491  156.356539     477
166  20190214  18:05:00  166.20  166.21  166.76  166.216068  160.387446  156.454583     289
167  20190214  18:10:00  165.31  165.35  166.47  166.107809  160.537827  156.543095     619
168  20190214  18:15:00  164.66  165.21  166.22  165.995583  160.679408  156.629333     679
169  20190214  18:20:00  165.01  165.04  165.99  165.876135  160.811547  156.713021     383
170  20190214  18:25:00  164.25  164.42  165.67  165.694118  160.920894  156.789707     620
171  20190214  18:30:00  164.30  164.30  165.40  165.519854  161.023291  156.864437     259
172  20190214  18:35:00  163.60  163.74  165.07  165.297372  161.105616  156.932850     433
173  20190214  18:40:00  163.68  164.08  164.87  165.145200  161.195748  157.003966     218
174  20190214  18:45:00  163.76  163.80  164.66  164.977050  161.274665  157.071588     137
175  20190214  18:50:00  163.80  163.98  164.52  164.852419  161.356645  157.140329     186
176  20190214  18:55:00  163.81  164.02  164.42  164.748367  161.437353  157.208783     309
177  20190214  19:00:00  163.80  163.85  164.31  164.636071  161.510463  157.274865      69
178  20190214  19:05:00  163.80  163.80  164.20  164.531562  161.579843  157.339792     207
179  20190214  19:10:00  163.70  163.75  164.11  164.433867  161.645605  157.403575     125
180  20190214  19:15:00  163.41  163.50  163.99  164.317133  161.701799  157.464236      80
181  20190214  19:20:00  163.16  163.50  163.89  164.214992  161.756290  157.524293     166
182  20190214  19:25:00  163.17  163.30  163.77  164.100618  161.803069  157.581763     160
183  20190214  19:30:00  163.07  163.07  163.63  163.971791  161.841461  157.636372     233
184  20190214  19:35:00  162.91  163.01  163.51  163.851567  161.876871  157.689841     309
185  20190214  19:40:00  162.84  162.90  163.39  163.732621  161.907875  157.741684     130
186  20190214  19:45:00  162.58  162.58  163.23  163.588543  161.928243  157.789826      63
187  20190214  19:50:00  162.20  162.34  163.05  163.432475  161.940720  157.835101     268
188  20190214  19:55:00  162.29  162.75  162.99  163.347166  161.965244  157.884006     509
189  20190215  04:00:00  160.86  161.62  162.72  163.131270  161.954782  157.921180      14
190  20190215  04:05:00  161.62  162.25  162.62  163.021111  161.963728  157.964253      36
191  20190215  04:10:00  161.88  161.99  162.50  162.892222  161.964524  158.004310      17
192  20190215  04:15:00  162.00  162.00  162.40  162.780695  161.965599  158.044068       1
193  20190215  04:20:00  161.06  161.06  162.13  162.565608  161.938157  158.074077       7
194  20190215  04:25:00  160.93  161.05  161.91  162.376157  161.911243  158.103689      25
195  20190215  04:30:00  161.05  161.05  161.74  162.210387  161.885145  158.133005       0
196  20190215  04:35:00  161.05  161.05  161.60  162.065339  161.859837  158.162030       0
197  20190215  04:40:00  161.16  161.16  161.51  161.952171  161.838630  158.191860       1
198  20190215  04:45:00  161.40  162.08  161.63  161.968150  161.845944  158.230548      49
199  20190215  04:50:00  162.18  162.18  161.74  161.994631  161.856067  158.269846       1
200  20190215  04:55:00  162.00  162.00  161.79  161.995302  161.860429  158.306962       1
201  20190215  05:00:00  162.00  162.25  161.88  162.027140  161.872234  158.346197       8
202  20190215  05:05:00  162.05  162.50  162.01  162.086247  161.891257  158.387528      24
203  20190215  05:10:00  162.38  162.38  162.08  162.122966  161.906067  158.427254       1
204  20190215  05:15:00  162.35  162.35  162.13  162.151345  161.919520  158.466286       1
205  20190215  05:20:00  162.21  162.21  162.15  162.158677  161.928322  158.503537      43
206  20190215  05:25:00  162.22  162.22  162.16  162.166343  161.937161  158.540517       4
207  20190215  05:30:00  162.30  162.30  162.19  162.183050  161.948156  158.577925       2
208  20190215  05:35:00  162.30  162.30  162.21  162.197669  161.958818  158.614960       2
209  20190215  05:40:00  162.33  162.33  162.24  162.214210  161.970066  158.651926       1
210  20190215  05:45:00  162.34  162.68  162.32  162.272434  161.991579  158.692006       9
211  20190215  05:50:00  162.60  162.65  162.39  162.319630  162.011531  158.731389       9
212  20190215  05:55:00  162.64  162.65  162.44  162.360926  162.030879  158.770380       5
213  20190215  06:00:00  162.00  162.00  162.35  162.315810  162.029943  158.802516      92
214  20190215  06:05:00  162.24  162.24  162.33  162.306334  162.036309  158.836720       2
215  20190215  06:10:00  162.20  162.25  162.31  162.299292  162.042784  158.870683       4
216  20190215  06:15:00  162.23  162.77  162.41  162.358131  162.064821  158.909482      87
217  20190215  06:20:00  163.00  163.00  162.52  162.438364  162.093160  158.950184      28
218  20190215  06:25:00  163.10  163.10  162.64  162.521069  162.123670  158.991475       1
219  20190215  06:30:00  163.40  163.50  162.81  162.643435  162.165377  159.036336      23
220  20190215  06:35:00  163.50  163.50  162.95  162.750506  162.205820  159.080751       0
221  20190215  06:40:00  163.25  163.25  163.01  162.812943  162.237462  159.122236      15
222  20190215  06:45:00  163.35  163.35  163.08  162.880075  162.271175  159.164303       2
223  20190215  06:50:00  163.62  163.64  163.19  162.975065  162.312655  159.208837       5
224  20190215  06:55:00  163.05  163.39  163.23  163.026932  162.345302  159.250441       5
225  20190215  07:00:00  161.77  161.77  162.94  162.869816  162.327868  159.275511     257
226  20190215  07:05:00  161.70  162.40  162.83  162.811089  162.330054  159.306601     228
227  20190215  07:10:00  162.19  162.37  162.74  162.755953  162.331264  159.337082      79
228  20190215  07:15:00  162.35  163.25  162.84  162.817709  162.359105  159.376017     183
229  20190215  07:20:00  163.01  163.01  162.87  162.841745  162.378829  159.412176      28
230  20190215  07:25:00  163.05  163.35  162.97  162.905277  162.408258  159.451358     171
231  20190215  07:30:00  163.20  163.20  163.02  162.942117  162.432251  159.488658     134
232  20190215  07:35:00  163.00  163.21  163.05  162.975603  162.455819  159.525686     147
233  20190215  07:40:00  163.30  163.35  163.11  163.022402  162.482915  159.563739      90
234  20190215  07:45:00  163.36  163.75  163.24  163.113352  162.521312  159.605394      54
235  20190215  07:50:00  163.90  164.49  163.49  163.285433  162.580969  159.653997     194
236  20190215  07:55:00  164.40  164.80  163.75  163.474754  162.648212  159.705201     240
237  20190215  08:00:00  161.70  164.32  163.87  163.580410  162.698873  159.751119    1167
238  20190215  08:05:00  163.65  163.79  163.85  163.606608  162.731937  159.791307     216
239  20190215  08:10:00  163.35  163.67  163.81  163.614532  162.760363  159.829901     153

Answer (score 1):

If that is all the data you have, you are calculating ewm 200 on 30 samples, so for sure you won't have the same results.

Comment: Here is 2 days worth of data and it still doesn't match marketwatch EWM200 of 155.70.